# Native query instead of createQueryBuilder in entity field type Symfony

Tags: sql, forms, symfony, doctrine

Maybe someone faced such a problem then please help. I want to add a dropdown field in formbuilder that would feed from native sql query. I made this in my form:

```
->add('extensionId', 'entity', [
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Insurance Company',
            'class' => 'Bundle:Product',
            'query_builder' => function (ProductRepository $repo) {
                return $repo->getPGOperPG();
            }
        ])
```

It works fine if i use createQueryBuilder, like this:

```
public function getPGOperPG()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('pgo')
        ->select('pgo')
        ->join('pgo.productGroups', 'pg')
        ->where('pg.id IN (677, 655, 625) AND pgo.isActive = true');
}
```

But i get error if use this:

```
public function getPGOperPG()
{
    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT product_group_option_id
    FROM product_groups_product_group_options
    WHERE product_group_id in (677, 655, 625)
    SQL;

    $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->getEntityManager());
    $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('Bundle\Entity\Product', 'pgo');

    return $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)
        ;
}
```

This is the error: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEoRJ.png). 
I understand that only CreateQueryBuilder object is expected.

Question: is there a way how i could pass native query to a dropdown field? maybe some other form type or smth?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Create choice form type instead of entity

Comment: @malcolm did you do smth like that? could you please please provide an example? the issue is killing me.

Comment: I did many times, the idea is simple: pass your repo to form builder (or call it in controller and pass array of results), make array from the result and add it to choice type field.